# Why can't I update a value through an immutable reference of a mutable reference of a mutable value?

Tags: rust

I found the following hard to understand:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: i32 = 10;
    {
        let y: &mut i32 = &mut x;
        *y += 10;
        println!("y={}", *y);
        let z: &&mut i32 = &y;

        // z += 10; // error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `&mut i32`
        // *z += 10; // binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `&mut i32`
        // **z += 10; //cannot assign to data in a `&` reference
    }
    println!("x={}", x);
}
```

When I include `*z += 10`, the error message is:

```
error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `&mut i32`
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         *z += 10; // binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `&mut i32`
   |         --^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         cannot use `+=` on type `&mut i32`
   |
   = help: `+=` can be used on 'i32', you can dereference `*z`: `**z`
```

which is exactly the same as `y += 10;`

Since `*z` has the type `&mut i32`, which is the same as `y`, why can `*y` be used to update the value of `x`, but `**z` can't?

Comment: I think the [explanation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0389) of the error explain it very well

Comment: I don't think so. If you run it with `*z += 10;` and it will give `help: += can be used on 'i32', you can dereference *z: **z`. And the error is exactly the same as `y += 10;`, but `*y += 10;` will work and `**z += 10;` won't work.

Answer (score 5):

## `mut` is short for `unique`

There's a blurry line between "mutable" and "unique", but "mutable" may lead to the wrong intuition in this case. `&mut` references are really *unique* references: they cannot be aliased. If you have a `&mut T`, you know that *while the reference exists*, the `T` will not be accessed (either to mutate or just to read) through *any* other reference.

(Although you normally need a unique reference to mutate a value, there are references that allow both aliasing and mutation. `&Cell<T>` is one: you don't need unique access to a `Cell` to mutate its contents. `&mut` references are always unique.)

The compiler may use the knowledge that a `&mut` reference cannot be aliased to perform optimizations. The [Aliasing section of the Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/aliasing.html) has some more details.

## `&` references are shared references

`&` references, on the other hand, can always be aliased by other `&` references. Anything that requires unique access to a `T` must guarantee that no other reference can be used to access the `T`. But a `&&mut T` can't guarantee that, because it could be aliased by *another* `&&mut T` -- exclusive access to the `T` is not preserved. But you can still use a `&&mut T` to get a regular `&T`, because that doesn't require unique access to the `&mut T`.

Naturally, this is all enforced by Rust's type system. Consider how `Deref` and `DerefMut` are defined:

1. [`Deref::deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#tymethod.deref) takes `&self` and returns `&Self::Target`. So you don't need unique access to `self` to get shared access to `*self`.
2. [`DerefMut::deref_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html#tymethod.deref_mut) takes `&mut self` to return `&mut Self::Target`. So you *do* need unique access to `self` to get unique access to `*self`.

And one more thing prevents you from getting a `&mut T` by simply dereferencing a `&&mut T`:

3. `&mut` references don't implement [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html).

Comment: *`&mut` references are really unique references: they cannot be aliased* — nitpick: [the **references** can be aliased, the referred-to-value may not](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1efac93dfa7b254c8afa0b002f62f3e9&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015). While we are usually pretty lax around this terminology, in questions specific to these details it's worth being very specific. There are a few other issues of this kind in the answer.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm using the term the same way the Nomicon does: [variables and pointers alias if they refer to overlapping regions of memory.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/aliasing.html#aliasing) There are arguments to be had about liveness and reborrowing but I don't agree that your example demonstrates aliasing of a `&mut` reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After reading it, somehow I get the feeling that `&` is only a concept for the language and if we have  `let y : &mut 32 = &mut x;` actually for compiler, if without any optimization, we won't have `y` allocated in the stack, am I right?

Comment: @fishbone I'm not sure what you mean exactly. If you're familiar with C, Rust's underlying execution model is essentially the same as C's, but `&` and `&mut` references are language features that allow the compiler to more easily reason about relationships that would be hard or impossible to express in C. Does that begin to address your question?

Comment: @trentcl thanks for the explanation. It's very clear.

Answer (score -1):

You missed a few `mut`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: i32 = 10;
    {
        let mut y: &mut i32 = &mut x;
        *y += 10;
        println!("y={}", *y);
        let z: &mut &mut i32 = &mut y;
        println!("z={}", z); // output: z=20
        println!("*z={}", *z); // output: *z=20
        println!("**z={}", **z); // output: **z=20

        **z += 10;
    }
    println!("x={}", x);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ccc47560055b66038199f6157b5609fa&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

- you want `y` to be mutable -> `let mut y`.
- you want `&y` to be mutable -> `... = &mut y`.
- you want to assign it to a `&mut z` and reference this as mutable => `let z: &mut &mut i32 = ...`

I think it's more intuitive when omiting the type:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 10;
    {
        let mut y = &mut x;
        *y += 10;
        println!("y={}", *y);
        let z = &mut y;

        **z += 10;
    }
    println!("x={}", x);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0400c680a81fa19532d5bdc261a72820&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: I understood OP to be asking specifically *why*, not *what changes do I need to make to get my code to work*.

Comment: But I don't want `y` itself to be mutable. Here I'd like the value borrowed by `y` to be mutable. In this example, `z` will have the ability to change the value of `y`, like `*z = &mut i;`,  which is not what I want.

Comment: This is not possible here. When looking at my second snippet, you can see why: You cannot borrow a reference as mutable if the reference itself is not mutable.

Comment: In this case we'd like to put `z` in a block. To be specific, what I mean is like this one [example code](https://gist.github.com/1dbd220e8685911086b109e3652f78b1). And I still don't understand why `mut` is necessary even `*z` has the same type as `y`.