# Cancelling a distributed lock inside a Mutex from another thread causes a deadlock

Tags: rust, locking, deadlock

I implemented a distributed lock based on ZooKeeper and I want to test cancellation of the distributed lock. This causes a dead lock.

Here is code using `AtomicUsize` to simulate the ZooKeeper distributed lock (I chose `AtomicUsize` just because it's easy to share between thread, not sure if I using it in a preferred way).
Code updated: 2019-08-22
[playground: `AtomicUsize` simulation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a72777e74cde68335d626ee02699d75c)

```rust
use std::{
    sync::{
        atomic::{self, Ordering},
        Arc, Mutex,
    },
    thread,
};

fn main() {
    // use AtomicUsize simulate zookeeper distrute lock;
    // acting as a remote lock mechanism
    let counter = Arc::new(atomic::AtomicUsize::new(1));

    let lock1 = DistrLock::new(counter.clone());
    let lock1_handle = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(lock1)));

    let counter_thread = counter.clone();
    let lock1_handle_thread = lock1_handle.clone();

    // simulate another machine use distribute lock
    let thandle = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut lock2 = DistrLock::new(counter_thread);

        println!("lock 1");
        lock2.acquire().expect("debug thread1 1"); // distribute lock acquired

        thread::sleep_ms(10_000);

        println!("lock2 release");
        lock2.release().expect("debug thread1 2");
    });

    // second thread try cancelling lock1
    let thandle = thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep_ms(2000); // lock1 mutex lock acquired in main thread wait for distribute lock

        println!("lock 3");
        lock1_handle_thread
            .lock() // wait for lock1 mutex release, dead lock because lock1 wait for distribute lock2 to release
            .expect("debug thread2 1")
            .cancel() // test cancel for distribute lock
            .expect("debug thread2 2");

        println!("lock 4"); // can not reach until lock 2 release,  means can't cancel lock1 until lock1 get the distribute lock
    });

    thread::sleep_ms(1000);

    println!("lock 2");
    lock1_handle
        .lock() // mutex lock acquired
        .expect("debug main 1")
        .acquire() // wait for distribute lock in_lock_2 to release
        .expect("debug main 1.1");

    lock1_handle
        .lock()
        .expect("debug main 2")
        .release()
        .expect("debug main 2.1");

    thandle.join().expect("debug main 3");
}

struct DistrLock {
    counter: Arc<atomic::AtomicUsize>,
    canceled: bool,
}

impl DistrLock {
    pub fn new(counter: Arc<atomic::AtomicUsize>) -> DistrLock {
        let lock = DistrLock {
            counter: counter,
            canceled: false,
        };

        lock
    }

    pub fn acquire(&mut self) -> Result<bool, ()> {
        loop {
            if self.canceled {
                return Ok(false);
            }

            if self.counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst) < 1 {
                thread::sleep_ms(500);
                continue;
            } else {
                // self.counter.store(self.counter.load(Ordering::Relaxed) - 1, Ordering::Relaxed);
                self.counter
                    .store(self.counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst) - 1, Ordering::SeqCst);
                return Ok(true);
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn release(&mut self) -> Result<(), ()> {
        // self.counter.store(self.counter.load(Ordering::Relaxed) + 1, Ordering::Relaxed);
        self.counter
            .store(self.counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst) + 1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn cancel(&mut self) -> Result<(), ()> {
        self.canceled = true;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

There would not be any problem implementing this in Python or C++ because I would not need a mutex to protect `ZkDistrLock`, I could just call `cancel` in a second thread.

But in Rust, if I lose the `Mutex`, the compiler will complain that the use of `lock1` is not thread safe.

Is there some way I can lose the `Mutex` or is there a different idiom that I can use?

My [original implementation](https://github.com/ianzhang1988/TaskDispatch/blob/master/Utility/src/zoo_lock.rs) and in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ce4bbd3544718dcef9c0e4a6f5bf9920). The playground includes the distributed lock implementation but not all code here, and can not compile.

Comment: You are using atomic orderings that aren't `SeqCst`. My rule of thumb is that using anything but `SeqCst` should be reserved for those people who really, honestly, truly, deeply understand what they are doing. I am not one of those people; are you? The usage of `foo.store(foo.load(...))` is not a good sign, based on my knowledge.

Comment: You need the `Mutex` because `acquire`, `release` and `cancel` take `&mut self`. You can't express `&mut self` in Python or C++. It seems reasonable to make those take `&self` so that you can use the lock by a shared reference, which is analogous to references in most other languages. (You will need to use interior mutability, e.g. `AtomicBool` for `bool`.)

Comment: @Shepmaster I chose atomic not because I understand it well, just it's easy to share between thread for simulation of a distribute lock, I simply don't know other method.

Comment: This was [cross-posted to the user's forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/cancelling-a-distributed-lock-inside-a-mutex-from-another-thread-causes-a-deadlock/31624?u=shepmaster).

Comment: @trentcl  In my original implementation, the `flag` is not the only attribute need to be mutable. Do I have to change all those attribute into some `atomic` type, any suggestion?

Comment: `&mut` is a *unique* reference, meaning it can't be held while other references exist. If you need to mutate other members through a *shared* reference (`&`), those members need to have interior mutability -- `Atomic`, or `Mutex`, or `UnsafeCell` if you know what you're doing. I'm not sure I understand the data structure you're trying to implement so I can't be more specific than that. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51789056/3650362) (I wrote) describes in more detail the difference between `&` and `&mut`.

Comment: @trentcl Thanks for the reply, having some new understanding. Can we say that all method of a struct take &self is an indicator that the instance of the struct can be shared between thread?

Comment: A method that takes `&self` is a method that can be called by a shared reference, but `&` is for all kinds of sharing, not only between threads. [Here's a blog post that illustrates some of the issues with shared mutability in single-threaded programs.](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2015/05/17/the-problem-with-shared-mutability/) In order to be shared between threads, a type must also implement `Sync`.